# Firefox does not show option for a pdf reader

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe-reader

When I open a pdf online from firefox, it always use a "pdf arranger" reader despite I have set a different reader (first the document viewer then the acrobat reader). In the `setting` --> `applications` --> `actions` there is no option for the document viewer or the acroreader

How do I change that?

Comment: Click the menu button and select Settings.
In the General panel, go down to the Applications section.
Find Portable Document Format (PDF) in the list and click the entry to select it.
Click the arrow under the Action column for the above entry and select the PDF viewer you wish to use from the drop-down menu. (if it is not there, then firefox needs to be freshened up)

Comment: @Nishnabe "In the setting --> applications --> actions there is no option for the document viewer or the acroreader"

Comment: It should be there, it works on my FF. I suppose if you were using some type of extreme privacy, maybe it would go missing. I would upgrade the browser or reinstall it. I don't know it this could be considered a Ubuntu question.